# Is there anyway to delete the entire row from spreadsheet where exists a duplicate value?

Tags: excel, sqlite, excel-formula, duplicates

I am not worrying about finding the duplicate value as much anymore. I've made a way to uniquely identify each cell I need to delete. But once I have those cells selected in that one column, is it possible to delete the corresponding value on the column next to it with the selected cell? I'd do it manually, but there are thousands...

I also have the data in a db, if there is a sql query that could do it better...

Comment: Do you have access to a database that you export the contents of the excel sheet to a table, delete the rows using SQL, then export the data back out to excel?

Comment: Yes. Is there a sql query you could suggest?

Comment: It's a simple sqlite db. I use a simple gui db editor called Base to run queries and adjust table and tuples. I'm on a mac too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a tool for that in the Data tab called "Remove Duplicates". [(link)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-HP010073943.aspx#BMremove_duplicate_values)

Without using that tool, you can try the following formula:

```
=countif(A$1:A1;A1)
```

Put it in D1 for example, and paste it down on every line. It will count the occurrences of a given value in row A; it will display "1" for the first occurrence, "2" for the second. You can then filter the list and delete only the lines with a "2".

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am using Office 2008

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hopefully this formula will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

If your list is sorted and you can't use the remove duplicates here's what I normally do.

In cell C2 put the formula:

```
=A1=A2
```

Then fill it down.  This should check each item in the list against the one above it.

Turn on autofilter and filter for "FALSE", that will be your unique list of items.  Copy and paste it into another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select the whole row/column and delete all of the data that is in that row/column where the number is on the left or the letter across the top on an Mac you just go over the the letter or the number and hold control and then click and that should bring up and drop down menu so you can delete or copy the whole row or column

Comment: I edited my question, is this possible? I'm not seeing how to do it